# Better way to conditionally fill a column in one df based on multiple values in a row in another df in R

Tags: r, dataframe, rows, conditional-operator

I have two dataframes that I would like to relate.

The first dataframe (LOC) has about two hundred animals studied over 5 years, so about 100000 point locations. I need to know what pack each animal was in during the study duration, but unfortunately, animals change packs every so often. I need each point location to have a pack name associated with it since I will base further analyses on the pack, not the individual.

The second dataframe (PACK) has pack affiliations for these three hundred animals, and each row represents an entry day and exit day into a pack. My real data is a table with about 700 rows, and each row represents how long that animal stayed in the pack. For example in the PACK dataframe below, animal "W1" was in SunnyLake in the first day of year "A", then on day 200 left and went to RainyLake and stayed there until the end of year "B" (a leap year).

Since I have so many animals and so many switches among years, I want to know a way to tell R which days the animal belonged to SunnyLake and RainyLake in the LOC table.

So far my approach has been the following, but it is slow. I'm pretty new to R, so I thought there must be a faster, more elegant way to do this. If you see a better solution, please let me know (and keep in mind I just started working in R a few months ago)!

My example data:

Location table

```
LOC <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 8, ncol = 4))
colnames(LOC) <- c("ID", "Yr", "Dy", "Pack")
LOC$ID <- "W1"
LOC$Yr <- rep(c("A", "B"), each = 4)
LOC$Dy <- c(4, 200, 300, 335, 3, 100, 150, 350)
LOC

  ID Yr  Dy Pack
1 W1  A   4   NA
2 W1  A 200   NA
3 W1  A 300   NA
4 W1  A 335   NA
5 W1  B   3   NA
6 W1  B 100   NA
7 W1  B 150   NA
8 W1  B 350   NA
```

Pack Table

```
PACK <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 3, ncol = 5))
colnames(PACK) <- c("ID", "Pack", "EnterDay", "ExitDay", "Yr")
PACK$ID <- "W1"
PACK$Pack <- c("SunnyLake", "RainyLake", "RainyLake")
PACK$EnterDay <- c(1, 201, 1)
PACK$ExitDay <- c(200, 365, 366)
PACK$Yr <- c("A", "A", "B")
PACK

  ID      Pack EnterDay ExitDay Yr
1 W1 SunnyLake        1     200  A
2 W1 RainyLake      201     365  A
3 W1 RainyLake        1     366  B
```

My way of steamrolling through each row in PACK and filling the "Pack" column in LOC

```
for (i in 1:nrow(PACK)){
  cat("LOC$Pack[LOC$ID == \"", as.character(PACK$ID[i]),"\" & LOC$Yr == \"", as.character(PACK$Yr[i]),"\" & LOC$Dy >= ", PACK$EnterDay[i], " & LOC$Dy <= ", PACK$ExitDay[i],"] <- \"", as.character(PACK$Pack[i]),"\"\n", sep="")  
}
```

That command prints the following, which I paste back into the console and run.

```
LOC$Pack[LOC$ID == "W1" & LOC$Yr == "A" & LOC$Dy >= 1 & LOC$Dy <= 200] <- "SunnyLake"
LOC$Pack[LOC$ID == "W1" & LOC$Yr == "A" & LOC$Dy >= 201 & LOC$Dy <= 365] <- "RainyLake"
LOC$Pack[LOC$ID == "W1" & LOC$Yr == "B" & LOC$Dy >= 1 & LOC$Dy <= 366] <- "RainyLake"
```

The resulting LOC table looks like this:

```
LOC
  ID Yr  Dy      Pack
1 W1  A   4 SunnyLake
2 W1  A 200 SunnyLake
3 W1  A 300 RainyLake
4 W1  A 335 RainyLake
5 W1  B   3 RainyLake
6 W1  B 100 RainyLake
7 W1  B 150 RainyLake
8 W1  B 350 RainyLake
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) sqldf** Try this:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select L.ID, L.Yr, L.Dy, P.Pack from LOC L left join PACK P
       on L.Yr = P.Yr and L.ID = P.ID and L.Dy between P.EnterDay and P.ExitDay")
```

giving:

```
  ID Yr  Dy      Pack
1 W1  A   4 SunnyLake
2 W1  A 200 SunnyLake
3 W1  A 300 RainyLake
4 W1  A 335 RainyLake
5 W1  B   3 RainyLake
6 W1  B 100 RainyLake
7 W1  B 150 RainyLake
8 W1  B 350 RainyLake
```

**2) dplyr** or

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(LOC, PACK, by = c("ID", "Yr")) %.% 
    filter((Dy >= EnterDay & Dy <= ExitDay) | is.na(Pack.y)) %.% 
    select(ID:Dy, Pack.y)
```

giving

```
  ID Yr  Dy    Pack.y
1 W1  A   4 SunnyLake
2 W1  A 200 SunnyLake
3 W1  A 300 RainyLake
4 W1  A 335 RainyLake
5 W1  B   3 RainyLake
6 W1  B 100 RainyLake
7 W1  B 150 RainyLake
8 W1  B 350 RainyLake
```

ADDED: Added second solution and improved both.  Fixed dplyr solution to not drop `LOC` rows witih no `PACK` row.

Comment: Thanks G. Grothendieck, I was wondering when I was going to have to try plyr; I like the simplicity of your second solution. I'll give it a try next week when I get back from the field!

Comment: Note that dplyr is a different package than plyr.

Comment: I was able to get the sqldf solution to work well, but I am struggling with the syntax for dplyr, not having used it before. My actual table does not have ID Yr Dy in sequence as headers in the table, maybe that's a problem? My code I'm trying:                  left_join(LOC, PACK, by = c("ID", "Yr")) %.% 
  filter(LOC$Dy >= PACK$EnterDay & LOC$WDy <= PACK$ExitDay) %.% 
  select(c(LOC$ID, LOC$Yr, LOC$Dy), Pack.y)

Comment: In terms of the original problem one could equivalently write `select(ID, Yr, Dy, Pack.y)` for the last line.

Comment: Thanks. I got the dplyr solution to work. It turns out that some of my values in my bigger tables were of different types (e.g., num compared to int, factor compared to chr). Once I fixed that it delivered, interesting that the sqldf solution didn't require the columns to be the same type.  One thing I don't really understand is how dplyr recognizes which table it's getting the information from if you don't specify the table first - for example, what if "Yr" was "YEAR_" in one table and "Yr" in another? My ID column is in both tables - how do I know which one dplyr is referencing?

Comment: Finally, a note: the sqldf solution did not get rid of locations which were not associated with a pack. The dplyr did get rid of them. I'll try to find a way to keep them with dplyr.

Comment: Both solutions use a left join but the difference is that in SQL all the conditions are part of the ON clause, i.e. they are part of the join so it works.  In dplyr we did a left join only on the equal part of the condition since there is no way to incorporate the between part in the join.  At that point we still have all `LOC` rows but the filtering subsequently removes the `LOC` rows with no `PACK` row.  I have now explicitly changed the filter condition to keep them.  In this case I think SQL more directly specifies what you want.

Answer (score 2):

First, don't create the `Pack` column in `LOC` at the beginning; it's not necessary.

```
LOC <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 8, ncol = 3))
colnames(LOC) <- c("ID", "Yr", "Dy")  # NOTE: No Pack column
LOC$ID <- "W1"
LOC$Yr <- rep(c("A", "B"), each = 4)
LOC$Dy <- c(4, 200, 300, 335, 3, 100, 150, 350)
```

Here's a method that uses data tables, which is likely to be much faster with large datasets.

```
library(data.table)
LOC      <- data.table(LOC,   key="ID,Yr")
PACK     <- data.table(PACK, key="ID,Yr")
LOC$Pack <-LOC[PACK,all=T][Dy>=EnterDay & Dy<=ExitDay,Pack]
LOC
#   ID Yr  Dy      Pack
# 1 W1  A   4 SunnyLake
# 2 W1  A 200 SunnyLake
# 3 W1  A 300 RainyLake
# 4 W1  A 335 RainyLake
# 5 W1  B   3 RainyLake
# 6 W1  B 100 RainyLake
# 7 W1  B 150 RainyLake
# 8 W1  B 350 RainyLake
```

And here's a method that uses data frames (and does not require `sqldf`).

```
M <- merge(LOC,PACK,by=c("ID","Yr"))
is.between <- function(x,low,hi)return(x>=low & x<=hi)
LOC$Pack <- with(M,M[is.between(Dy,EnterDay, ExitDay),]$Pack)
```

Comment: These solutions work with the test data but will drop any row of `LOC` for which there is no corresponding row in `PACK`.

Comment: Ok - good to know. I'd rather loose a column in PACK than LOC.